# strange thing happens when I plot a simple graph

Tags: r, plot

```
rdata <- c(
0.00000000,0.09370000,0.37500000,0.84370000,1.50000000,2.34370000,3.37500000,
4.59370000,5.99990000,7.59360000,9.37490000,11.34360000,13.49980000,15.84350000,
18.37480000,21.09350000,23.99970000,27.09340000,30.37460000,33.84330000,37.49950000,
0.09376236,0.37504944,0.84371981,1.49991490,2.34377614,3.37502067,4.59364849,
5.99994246,7.59361972,9.37482170,11.34354841,13.49979982,15.84357596,18.37473539,
21.09341955,23.99962842,27.09336201,30.37462031,33.84326192,37.49956966
)
fitted <- c(
 0.000000e+00,5.753386e-05,9.215290e-04,4.664786e-03,1.474561e-02,3.600278e-02,
 7.467473e-02,1.383905e-01,2.362147e-01,3.786691e-01,5.778025e-01,8.472223e-01,
1.202270e+00,1.660126e+00,2.240041e+00,2.963485e+00,3.854605e+00,4.940527e+00,
6.251861e+00,7.823289e+00,9.694269e+00,5.761047e-05,9.217720e-04,4.665005e-03,
1.474393e-02,3.600511e-02,7.467565e-02,1.383874e-01,2.362180e-01,3.786710e-01,
5.777928e-01,8.472146e-01,1.202270e+00,1.660142e+00,2.240025e+00,2.963462e+00,
3.854581e+00,4.940513e+00,6.251870e+00,7.823270e+00,9.694307e+00
)
plot(rdata,fitted,'l')
```

When I plot the data in type 'l', a straight line and a curve appear. The curve is what I expected. But the straight line lines up the starting value and the ending value, which is very strange. Can anyone help me to remove that line?

Comment: could you make your problem reproducible?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is arising because the "rdata" vector is not in order (e.g., element 22 is 0.09, but element 21 is ~37)

Comment: @rbatt, that's right.  I tried `plot(sort(rdata),sort(fitted))` which seems to work (but is dangerous as a general strategy since the two vectors might not have the same kind of non-sortedness)

Comment: @BenBolker Did you make that edit manually, or is there an easy way to convert that type of output into reproducible code?

Comment: manual edit (with some regex searching and replacing in Emacs).  It would be nice to have an automated tool ...

Answer (score 1):

First, put data in a matrix:

`mat <- cbind(rdata, fitted)`

Then, reorder the matrix according to the `rdata` column:

`mat2 <- mat[order(mat[,1]),]`

Now, the plot should work fine :)

`plot(mat2, typ="l")`

Edit: Is this the legend you want? I don't quite understand, because you only plotted the line, which I'm assuming is the "fitted" line – what are the x-y coordinates for the observed data?

`legend("topleft", legend=c("Observed", "Fitted"), lty=c(NA, 1), pch=c(19, NA))`

Here is the figure that is produced:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!One more question:how do you make line type of the legend be one point and one line? I tried legend(1,15,c('Observation','Fitted'),lty=c(0,1),pch=21,lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c('red','blue'))  which gives me a point and a line with a point in the middle.

Comment: @user3624246 Comments are not good places for new questions. It's better to start a new post so more people will see your question and can answer it. Also, there is an example that does just that on the `?legend` help page so you probably should check that out.

Comment: @user3624246 If it was a good answer, consider upvoting and accepting by clicking the checkmark :)